# UIDatePicker crash on iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, crash, uidatepicker, ios-4.2

i've a problem with ios 4.2.1 and uidatepicker.
My app is running on iPad and the picker is inside an UIPopoverController.
On iOS 3.2 the app works fine.
When i spin any wheel of the picker, the app crash with this stack trace:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01165be9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x012ba5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0115b6e5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
    3   UIKit                               0x002e9b74 -[UIPickerView reloadComponent:] + 62
    4   UIKit                               0x004cb6a9 -[UIDatePickerView _updateDateOrTime] + 1273
    5   UIKit                               0x004cb114 -[UIDatePickerView pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:] + 42
    6   UIKit                               0x002e9194 -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedForComponent:] + 100
    7   UIKit                               0x002e8f75 -[UIPickerView scrollerDidEndSmoothScrolling:] + 75
    8   UIKit                               0x004924c7 -[UIScroller(Internal) _stopScrollingNotify:dealloc:pin:] + 692
    9   UIKit                               0x00493ed0 -[UIScroller(Static) _smoothScroll:] + 4743
    10  UIKit                               0x0048a188 ScrollerHeartbeatCallback + 129
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x01a9d447 HeartbeatTimerCallback + 35
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x01146fe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 19
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x01148594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x010a4cc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x010a4240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x010a4161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x01a9a268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x01a9a32d GSEventRun + 115
    19  UIKit                               0x0030242e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  Agenda                              0x0000245c main + 102
    21  Agenda                              0x000023ed start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved! The problem was the maximum date. I set the timeComponent without specifying the year so the default date was 01-01-0001 this causes the crash.
Setting the year to 2010 solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your array range.

Comment: yes... but i haven't any array declared :)

@interface HoursController : InfoViewController {
 UIDatePicker* picker;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIDatePicker* picker;
@end

Comment: I'm debugging the code and i see that setting maximun date causes the crash when i spin the wheel.
hoursController.picker.maximumDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:timeComp];
PS: I'm sorry for my bad english :)